# SQL Server field is an identity , but Entity Framework EDMX only inserts when StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity"

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, edmx

I have wiped all files.  Gotten Specific version,  all files are identical but other developers on my team with .net 4.5.2   EDMX of Entity Framework,  there edmx code has

```
<Property Name="Id" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
```

Which is correct as the database table has that Id column as a seeding identity.
It is NOT working for me , so from my computer I have to do

```
<Property Name="Id" Type="int" Nullable="false" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
```

> 1. WHY is this happening, and how to fix?
> 2. If I publish MY code to a server, will it "break" things?  (saying explicitly it is identity when it already is?
> 3. This a known bug?
> 4. Should other developers just do what I'm doing instead ?

Comment: The database being used by you and other developers is the same? Are you sure you are looking connecting to the right table of right database? If you remove `StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity"` what behavior you notice? Any error from EF or SQL Server?

Comment: *seeding identity* -- Do you mean the column is an identity column with a seed value?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya     for sure the same database etc.     and error is sql server / EF says in  catch block in C# that cannot insert null into indentity column of Id

Comment: @GertArnold  -   Yes

Comment: By any chance other developers using any attribute on the `Id` property like "DatabaseGeneratedAttribute" ? Silly question but I wanted to rule out that option.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya    nope

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *which is correct*. It isn't. There should be `StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity"` in the file. Do the others actually insert new items into the database with this code? Hard to believe.

Comment: Yes - that is what blows me away.   I see on their computers and getting from TFS version control.    SMH.  :/    thx

Comment: Whatever it is, the error *cannot insert null into identity column* unequivocally proves that the table *doesn't* have an identity column, which means that `StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity"` should *not* be there. If you're convinced that the table does have an identity column you're looking at something else.